# Odd filesystem behavior lately

Tags: bash, filesystem

Recently I've had a spate of problems where files have just... disappeared. Not necessarily relevant but I have a directory for a Plex library for TV shows, and Plex has had no trouble finding files I put there. Starting about a week ago, files that I put there would just disappear, from the shell, from Plex, from every way I could look. I've been wracking my pitiful brain trying to figure out what could be happening, and I remembered a limit on file/directory entries in DOS... so I did a 'df -i' to see what it had to say.

The part that's actually my question is why does 'df -i' display zeroes for some of my drives? To wit:

```
/dev/sdd1      729247032 699451 728547581    1% /media/dave/Much Disk
/dev/sdc2              0      0         0     - /media/dave/Such Disk
/dev/sdb1              0      0         0     - /media/dave/Only 8
```

Any insight appreciated!

Comment: Which filesystems are used in this partitions? Are they NTFS or FAT?

Comment: Also do not use spaces. Use CamelCase, under_score, or just onelabel. Otherwise you have to escape space or use quotes so first part is not just what is seen.

Comment: Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Comment: The devices displaying zeroes are both NTFS,

Comment: @ADave That's the reason, afaik NTFS does not have that concept of inodes like in linux, maybe something similar but `df` can't make use of that and sets inode number to zero.